# Is $\sqrt{-1}$ irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Apologies if this is obvious. I have searched for similar questions but I haven't found one that answers this.

Simply, is $\sqrt{-1}$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$? Whether it is or isn't, please explain why.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is meaningless since $i$ is a unit in this ring.

Comment: Sorry, would you explain what you mean?

Comment: Only non-units can be irreducible by definition.

Comment: So is $i$ a unit because the entire ring is $i$? (Eek sorry that sounds dim)

Comment: $i(-i)=(-i)i=1$

Comment: $i$ is a unit because $-i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $i \cdot (-i) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you all - should have been obvious but it's been a long day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an element to be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{ a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } i = \sqrt{-1} \}$, its divisors (note that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean norm) must be "units" and "associates". You can easily find definitions to these terms online. The units in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$ since the norm of these elements, given by $N(z)=N(a+bi) = a^2 + b^2, $ equal $1$. Thus, $i$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.